# FubuMvc: how to use layouts in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, fubumvc

Very simple helloworld fubumvc app and I'm not able to make it work with layouts using Razor.

here is a sample code: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4740987

Comment: Include the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FubuMVC also relies on using the layout directive instead of the code block.

Example:
@layout Application

Answer (score 1):

I keep the Application.cshtml under /Shared folder in the project root, and do not explicitly set the @Layout property and everything is rendered fine.

Perhaps you are missing some packages from NuGet.

It is unclear from the provided files of the kind of issue you end up with.